# Can Grails read from remote directory of files?

Tags: java, linux, grails, groovy, file-sharing

We have two linux servers set up with a folder on each for all of our BIRT reports. Our application will be deployed to a test server, and a production server. The test server deployment will read from the test report folder, and the production from the production versions. Simple model, everything should be do-able.

My question is how do I tell this BIRT plugin that the reports are out on another box under some path?

`birt.reporthome = ''` is the config we need to have pointing out to the linux boxes. I'm just having a tough time trying to figure out the syntax for pointing to the other machine. It will need to be a dns name in the uri, as the linux boxes are clustered and load balanced.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you download the config in each server on startup? You can add it to your bootstrap something like:

```
new File("/tmp/birtconfig").text = "dnsname/fileName".toUrl().text
```

And your variable pointed to

```
birt.reporthome = /tmp/birtconfig
```

You will be sure that this works despite the other server falls down.

Comment: It's not the config that's on the servers, its a directory of roughly 290 files.